# Replacing strings against template stories in Rally

Tags: python, rally

I can successfully obtain user story information with my Python code; however, I want to replace a specific string located in the details and user story name. For instance, the string could be $projectName and I'd like to replace it with a user inputted value.

Is there something which helps to code for this or is there a working example? I am stuck because this isn't necessarily a file to edit and the Hierarchy output also creates a block for me to develop something that works.

Here is my code for pulling the data:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
from pyral import Rally, rallyWorkset

options = [arg for arg in sys.argv[1:] if arg.startswith('--')]
args    = [arg for arg in sys.argv[1:] if arg not in options]
server, username, password, apikey, workspace, project = rallyWorkset(options)
if apikey:
        rally = Rally(server, apikey=apikey, workspace=workspace, project=project)
else:
        rally = Rally(server, username=username, password=password, workspace=workspace, project=project)
response = rally.get ('UserStory', fetch=True, query='Name contains "$projecttest"')
for story1 in response:
    print story1.details()
```

---

Here is the output I get, scrubbed, of course:

```
HierarchicalRequirement
    oid                       : 81284473268
    ref                       : hierarchicalrequirement/81284473268
    ObjectID                  : 81284473268
    ObjectUUID                : 67c952b4-e414-4759-a8c5-d7d7543ba98d
    _ref                      : https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/hierarchicalrequirement/81284473268
    _CreatedAt                : Dec 14, 2016
    _hydrated                 : True
    Name                      : Robert - test - pyRal - $projecttest
    Subscription              : <<SCRUBBED>>
    Workspace                 : Workspace.ref          (OID  SCRUBBED)
    FormattedID               : US47008

    AcceptedDate              : None
    Attachments               : []
    Blocked                   : False
    BlockedReason             : None
    Blocker                   : None
    Changesets                : []
    Children                  : []
    CreationDate              : 2016-12-14T18:21:03.663Z
    DefectStatus              : NONE
    Defects                   : []
    Description               : <b>Description</b><div><br /><div>Some format here</div><div><br /></div><div><b>Outcome</b></div><div><b><br /></b></div><div>Some outcome here</div></div>
    DirectChildrenCount       : 0
    Discussion                : []
    DisplayColor              : #21a2e0
    DragAndDropRank           : O~zbf~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Expedite                  : False
    Feature                   : None
    HasParent                 : False
    InProgressDate            : None
    Iteration                 : None
    LastBuild                 : None
    LastRun                   : None
    LastUpdateDate            : 2016-12-19T22:42:48.173Z
    LatestDiscussionAgeInMinutes  : None
    Milestones                : []
    Notes                     : 
    Owner                     : User.ref  (OID  SCRUBBED)
    Package                   : None
    Parent                    : None
    PassingTestCaseCount      : 0
    PlanEstimate              : None
    PortfolioItem             : None
    Predecessors              : []
    Project                   : Project.ref                 (OID  SCRUBBED)
    Ready                     : False
    Recycled                  : False
    Release                   : None
    ScheduleState             : Ungroomed
    ScheduleStatePrefix       : U
    Successors                : []
    Tags                      : []
    TaskActualTotal           : 0.0
    TaskEstimateTotal         : 0.0
    TaskRemainingTotal        : 0.0
    TaskStatus                : NONE
    Tasks                     : []
    TestCaseCount             : 0
    TestCaseStatus            : NONE
    TestCases                 : []
    VersionId                 : 4
    __collection_ref_for_RevisionHistory  : SCRUBBED
    _refObjectUUID            : SCRUBBED
    AcceptanceCriteria        : None
    IGNOREAcceptanceCriteria  : None
    IdeaURL                   : <pyral.entity.CustomField object at 0x7f1afb79a190>
    IdeaVotes                 : None
    JIRAPriority              : None
    JiraKey                   : None
    JiraLink                  : None
    KanbanState               : None
    Priority                  : None
    ReleaseNote               : None
    RequestedDate             : None
    SNRequest                 : None
    Submitter                 : None
    TestRailPlanID            : None
    TrackingState             : None
```

=====================================================

So, with PyRal, I would have to send an update to each user story this code pulls, only on the rows which contain the string; however, I would somehow have to store each FormattedID: and the associated Name: field to update, this is where I am stuck, on how to actually store this so it can be iterated over and updated.

Comment: If you're just looking to replace things like `$projectName` in a string, this is not a difficult task, but you haven't shown us any attempt. Try using regular expressions and the `re` module.

Comment: Sorry for that, I was in a hurry, I have updated my post.

Answer (score 0):

You could use *template strings* which do exactly what you want, using an env-variable like to delimit template tokens:

```
from string import Template
s = Template('this is $projectName')
s.substitute(projectName='THE_PROJECT')
```

results in:

```
'this is THE_PROJECT'
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html

Alternate way, if you wrap `projectName` within curly braces, is using `format`:

```
s = 'this is {projectName}'
print(s.format(projectName='THE_PROJECT'))
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought about this; however, using PyRal, I have to make a separate call to update the record; thus, I would need to store the FOrmattedID and the Name and then edit only the string inside the name and apply the update to the respective FormattedID (story).